# How can I show in a figure the converted image with the split function?

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, split

How can I show the image using matplotlib?

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = Image.open('lena.png')
colors = img.split()
RED = colors[0]
```

I showed the original image and the histogram but I could not show the red picture.

```
plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.imshow(RED)
plt.show()
```

I showed the original picture and the histogram but I could not show the red picture.Error message on last line:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'mask'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the PIL image to a numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
# ...
plt.imshow(np.array(RED))
```

Comment: It is not the same as the image created using RED.show ().The image created with nP.Array (RED) also dominates the green tone.what I want to say is: https://imgur.com/a/hc9M3   
sorry for my bad english.
thanks for your comment.

Comment: The red channel is a grey scale image. You may choose any colormap you like to show it. If you don't like the default one, use e.g. `plt.imshow(np.array(RED), cmap="gray")` or `plt.imshow(np.array(RED), cmap="Reds_r")`.